# How to type a function which returns a function's result from a collection of functions in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this function which receives an object of functions, chooses one based on some conditions, and call and return one of the functions:

```
type ProductName = 'product1' | 'product2' | 'product3' | 'product4';
function detectProduct(): ProductName  {
    return 'product1'; // for demo purpose
}

export function onAnyProduct<T extends Partial<Record<ProductName, () => any>>> (
    productCallbacks: T
): ReturnType<T[keyof T]> | undefined {
    const name = detectProduct();
    const callback = productCallbacks[name];
    return callback?.();
}

const a = onAnyProduct({
    product1: () => '1',
    product2: () => ({}),
});
```

You can check it out on TypeScript playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwByBDAttAXigHIxFUMBGYqAHxLOXWACYb7TzmBmdhrjABZiAbgBQAMxQA7DAEsE0qEgjAIGeEwwAKAJQAuWAKx5oUAN5io1qHFUo4SzluDURUAPQeoEhHGUQuAhQYA5gCADOEGIAvmJiEAAe4XDAPjLyilCKAILSIJoUwAA8ACpQSWrSSBGw2Kly2AA2xQBK6n5IxYXMOPgANFB6UAQAfFDY+aPTQ1Y2jEUAws1NAEbYaADWEYalYgZQ7cAO0qXgEGUA2psQIAgSUKUAuuP0MioSctIQSBZz1mhFBE0tJTCMAmoNMY9OIbFBAdJgfCVustuCFsxlk01httpdQfgnrCbHZjo5kdjUZsAPwAOhhsXiCKR2HBuXyPR0ljhGKohmGYxI1H6-xCxhY-N0I3G2nMMV0IvlIiAA

As you see, there is a problem with `T[keyof T]`, but `a` has correct type of `const a: string | {} | undefined`.

Why it doesn't know that `T[keyof T]` is a function?

Answer (score 0):

Because after you extend the your record type, the key/value of extends object can be anything, not only exactly `ProductName` and `() => {}`.

```
Type 'T[keyof T]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'
=> keyof T = string | number | symbol
Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'
```

```js
type ProductName = 'product1' | 'product2' | 'product3' | 'product4';
function detectProduct(): ProductName  {
    return 'product1'; // for demo purpose
}

// because you mark T as extended of Partial type
// then T["product1"] = () => any | undefined
// then you should use NonNullable
export function onAnyProduct<T extends Partial<Record<ProductName, () => any>>> (
    productCallbacks: T
): ReturnType<NonNullable<T["product1"]>> | undefined {
    const name = detectProduct();
    const callback = productCallbacks[name];
    return callback?.();
}

const a = onAnyProduct({
    product1: () => '1',
    product2: () => ({}),
});
```

Comment: The `T["product1"]` should be `T[keyof T]`, right?

Comment: Nope, keyof T can be somethings else "product1", "extendname".